# Can't restore 2017 (1200) Tabular model in 2016 DB (also 1200)

Tags: ssas, restore, tabular

I developed a tabular model using a 2017 Developer DB for both data source and deployment server. Compatibility level set to 1200.

From the deployment server, I backed it up to as ABF file which I moved to a 2016 Developer server and tried to restore it.

The server gave me "The embedded PowerPivot data in the workbook cannot be loaded due to a version mismatch." error.

(Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE0qE.jpg )

I don't understand what PowerPivot has to do with anything.

Also shouldn't I be able to import if the compatibility levels are the same?

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we usually restore an older version database on a newer version(cannot restore a database from new to an earlier version of Analysis Services).

In addition, when you restore, you need to make sure location must be the same server type.

Zoe